# KeyDown event doesn't work when ComboBox is opened?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

Why is the `KeyDown` event not triggered when the `ComboBox` dropdown is opened?
Is there any way to trigger this.

I'm trying to use `KeyDown` event to check which key is pressed and automatically selecting an item from the `ComboBox` which starts with the pressed character simulating a partial Auto Complete feature. But this does not work when the `ComboBox` is opened.

Code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="statusComboBox" KeyDown="ComboBox_KeyDown"/>

statusComboBox.ItemsSource = inspectionStatusComboList;

private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;
    int index = -1;
    string key = e.Key.ToString();

    if (key.Length == 1)
    { 
       switch(box.Name)
       {
          case "statusComboBox":
                    index = inspectionStatusComboList.IndexOf(inspectionStatusComboList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(key)));
                    break;
       }
       box.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Here is a clip of what I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

Comment: Show some code, otherwise its hard to help

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari : Added code.

Comment: Have you tried catching the preview event rather than the actual event?

Comment: @LordWilmore: Preview event?

Comment: UIElement.PreviewKeyDown.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But I have multiple ComboBoxes and since this event is not related to a ComboBox rather a general Keyboard event I wouldn't be knowing which ComboBox to apply the selection to.

Comment: have you set a breakpoint and debugged to see if the ComboBox_KeyDown method is firing at all? The problem might not be with the method itself.. But normally Method names like "ComboBox_KeyDown" fires specifically on the KeyDown event on the control with the ID ComboBox

Comment: The event fires when the ComboBox dropdown is not opened. But it doesn't fire once the ComboBox is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine the dropdown popup getting focus, so you'd have to get access to that and subscribe to key events on that as well. See the template [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408(v=vs.95).aspx) for reference. You could try subscribing to these events on the `Popup` or `PopupBorder` elements.

You could also use the [`AutoCompleteTextBox`](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/AutoCompleteTextBox) from my [toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit/) instead.

Comment: Hey Filip, thanks for your help, I've tried the AutoCompleteTextBox from your toolkit, Firstly thanks a lot for the help, but like in my case I need the dropdown even if there are no values in the textbox and I wasn't able to achieve that in my case with your toolkit. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Do you mean alternative auto complete implementations? I'm sure there are. You could also just grab the one from the toolkit and make changes to make it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing KeyRoutedEventArgs to KeyEventArgs and see you get it going, since we cant see the rest of your code to see if you create the routes

Comment: Could you elaborate? As I can't just substitute since it wont match any overloaded KeyDown events?